# Fail to filter pandas dataframe by categorical column

Tags: python, pandas

pandas 0.16.1
I converted all columns in dataframe to categoricals so it takes MUCH less space when dumped to disk. Now i want to filter dataframe. It's ok with == and .isin but fails on <, <=, etc. operations with "Unordered Categoricals can only compare equality or not"

```
data[data["MONTH COLUMN"]<=3]
```

If i comment out the following lines in categorical.py everything works fine. Is it a bug in pandas?

```
if not self.ordered:
    if op in ['__lt__', '__gt__','__le__','__ge__']:
        raise TypeError("Unordered Categoricals can only compare equality or not")
```

I think it was a good idea to use Categorical datatype on column which has only 12 unique values in ~1'400'000 rows.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/categorical.html#working-with-categories) states:

> **Note** New categorical data are NOT automatically ordered. You must explicity pass ordered=True to indicate an ordered Categorical.

When you first create a category you want to be ordered, just specify this:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: s = pd.Series(["a","b","c","a"]).astype('category', ordered=True)

In [5]: s
Out[5]: 
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    a
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [a < b < c]

In [4]: s > 'a'
Out[4]: 
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: i thought that order is irrelevant, cause i need only to filter by value. Anyway i get "_astype() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ordered'" on data[...] = data[...].astype('category', ordered=True)

Comment: @Winand see update. It works fine by me; perhaps you need to update your `pandas` ver.

Comment: oh, i cannot convert categorical to ordered categorical this way. That works: .astype('int64').astype('category', ordered=True).

Comment: There's also 'set_ordered' function. Completely different option - avoid categorical on filtering data[data["A"].astype(data["A"].cat.categories.dtype)<=3]